# How can I tell if a mod will disable Steam Achievements?

Tags: steam, achievements, mods, banished

I recently came to the knowledge that having mods enabled for a game results in gaining no Steam achievements (Wish I knew this earlier..spent so many hours already).

However I was wondering if this means that even a **single** active mod will put a stop in obtaining the achievements, or whether there are some mods that are 'safe' to install.

Is there a list of mods that I should avoid or some way of telling whether a mod will disable achievements? Or is disabling all of them the only way out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, the only achievements you can get with mods installed in most games are ones that actually come with the mods. Some official mods/DLC (like Skyrim) are exceptions to this rule, because the mods/addons are made in a way that doesn't disrupt the work needed to get the achievements. If you had a mod in Banished that tripled the output of resources for example, getting those resource-specific achievements would be much easier.

I've had single mods disable achievements before, and I'd assume that any non-official mod would do the same, every time. If it does disable achievements for one mod installed, it's likely embedded code in the core game that makes the achievement system disabled.